# fwrite vulnerability

Tags: php, file-upload

This is my original code to upload text files in my website:

```
<?php
$myFile = $_GET['myFile'];
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET['stringData'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Is it secure enough for you or should I use something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['myFile'])) {
    $myFile = basename($_GET['myFile']);
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
}
$stringData = $_GET['stringData'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you think that simply wrapping a `basename()` call around your incoming data will provide any security benefits? Also, why would you not have the part where you actually write and close to the file handle inside the `if` statement in your second example?  you will get errors trying to write and close to a non-existent file handle in the case where `$_GET['myFile']` is not set.

Answer (score 1):

First code does not upload files to your server, it just creates a text file with the name and content specified in the client's side.

The second code can fail, if you do not specify the value of `myFile`: The second part will try to write in a file that was never created.

Answer (score 1):

you basically allow to upload any file to current directory....

For example upload a php scripts that does whatever attacker wants

No... you should never write code like that.

1. Make sure you upload files only to specific location.
2. You give them names - never accept from user.
3. LEARN more...